# How Slick update JSONB column in PG?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, jsonb, slick-pg

I try to update column `attrs` (JSONB type) in this way, it compiles failed.

```
table
   .filter(_.sn === param.sn)
   .map(_.attrs)
   .update(param.attrs)
```

But if I update a INTEGER column in the same way, it succeed.

How should I update a JSONB column by Slick ?

Comment: Do you use slick-pg? (You have to in order to use JsonB types.)

Comment: @Simon Yes, I use slick-pg already. And the JSONB type is mapped to org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue type in Scala Class. But the codes above still compiles failed.